# Replacing pacemaker ip addresses with static IPs and then back again

Tags: networking, ubuntu-20.04, pacemaker, corosync

Looking to upgrade corosync/pacemaker, a problem is that version 2 and 4 of corosync cannot communicate.

Having 3 nodes, on Ubuntu 20.04, seems like it will lead to a momentary split brain, will all nodes upgrade and come back on, even if I carefully put them on standby and everything falls over to 1 host.

So I'm thinking: what if I:

1. Made those IP addresses static
2. Do the upgrade on all machines
3. Have pacemaker take over again. Meaning: ip addresses are no longer static but virtual/floating.

Problem is: I can't seem to find documentation on this. SEO seems to just send me to general articles about pacemaker.

I'm at a loss for how to do this, maybe someone here knows or can steer me in the right direction?

Any help is appreciated.